# The meaning of ‘remain’ in a sentence

Tags: phrase-meaning

“The role of science in modern society remains valuable.”

I think this sentence suggests that the role of science still has a positive impact on modern society. But another thought runs through my mind that the writer suggests whether the role of science has a beneficial influence in modern society.

Which one explicitly represents the meaning of this sentence, or give your explanations of your thoughts with some examples?

Comment: "Remain" refers  to "to continue to be in the specified state."They are as useful as  it was before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence states that science has a **valuable role** in modern society. There's nothing stated or implied to suggest that science has a **beneficial influence**. A valuable role doesn't have to be beneficial (for example, it might just be symbolic).